# can't add control to usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

This works:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Comments.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_Comments" %>

Add comment
```

But this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Comments.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_Comments" %>

Add comment
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="lol" />
```

Throws this error I've never seen before:

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.Control.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(System.Web.UI.Page)' has some invalid arguments

Source Error:


Line 190:            #line hidden
Line 191:            this.lol = @__ctrl;
Line 192:            @__ctrl.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(this.Page);
Line 193:            
Line 194:            #line 5 "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ScirraNew\Controls\Comments.ascx"

Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\scirranew\3a1c901c\f2f0205e\App_Web_comments.ascx.cc671b29.aem6dvrt.0.cs    Line: 192
```

Any help appreciated, I can't see much on google about it :( I have added it to web.config this way:

```
<add tagPrefix="Scirra" src="~/Controls/Comments.ascx" tagName="Comments"/>
```

Page code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Controls_Comments : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Anchor (GUID/UniqueIdentifier) for the comments
    /// </summary> 
    public System.Guid Anchor { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Comment page to load
    /// </summary>
    public int Page { get; set; }

    public int TotalComments { get; set; }
    public int TotalPage { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual exception message? For example, what does the compiler error say or what is the yellow screen of death saying?

Comment: @Tejs I've updated the error with everything on the yellow screen

Comment: Sounds like something in your code behind.

Comment: @Tej I pasted codebehind in, it's doing nothing :(  Also the error doesn't appear if there is no server control present

Comment: I've tried removing the control and adding a new one different names, no luck same behaviour

Comment: Possibly some codefile/codebehind/desinger/temporary cache issue? I bet there's some conflict somewhere. Try a clean build, check for the presence of any cs files you aren't using that have conflicting class names... e.g. if not part of the project will not prevent compilation but will be picked up at run time.

Comment: Are you using themes or skins with a style applied to `Button` controls?

Comment: Thanks everyone, solved, int Page, Page is a reserved word refering to the page :S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your declaring a public property named Page, which is an integer:

```
public int Page { get; set; }
```

And then your using this property to apply the stylesheet skin:

```
@__ctrl.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(this.Page);
```

Try renaming your property to something else (PageCount, NumberOfItemsOnPage, PageID, etc.).
Or assign the correct type to this property:

```
public System.Web.UI.Page Page { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also had this strange issue and it had me pulling my hair out.  Then I hit me....

1.) I had started a new VS 2010 C# Web project

2.) I deleted a bunch of the auto-generated project files (including Site.Master)

3.) I started building up my basic code framework

4.) I created a new Site.Master file

5.) When I added the first server control (Label) to the Site.Master I started getting the error

6.) Then it hit me, maybe something was stuck in temp files, designer files, or cache where it was still trying compile (call it a) ghost (for a lack of a better term) of the original Site.Master file that did not have the new Label control added.

I renamed my new Site.Master file to SiteMaster.Master and the site operated correctly again.  (Obviously I had to update all my child pages to use the new correct master page).

Not sure where the original Site.Master ghost file was hiding.  Even tried killing all the Temporary ASP.NET Files from C:\, Rebuilding Project, Clean Project, restarting VS, restarting PC, etc.  Super weird.

But just thought I'd share this stupid mistake that ran me in circles for 20 minutes before I figured it out!

Best!